# Is $\alpha :=\sup_{n \ge 2} \sup_{1 \le k \le n} S_{n, k}$ finite or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, supremum-and-infimum

Given a natural number $n \ge 2$, we define

- a finite sequence $(t_{n,i})_{i=0}^n$ by $t_{n, 0} := 0, t_{n, n} := \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and
  $$
  t_{n, i+1} := t_{n, i} + \frac{1}{ (n - i)^2}
  \quad \forall i \in \{0, \ldots,n-2\}.
  $$
- a finite sequence $(S_{n,k})_{k=1}^{n}$ by
  $$
  S_{n, k} :=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{t_{n, i+1} - t_{n, i}}{t_{n, k} - t_{n, i}}
  \quad \forall k \in \{1, \ldots,n\}.
  $$

> Could you elaborate if
> $$
> \alpha :=\sup_{n \ge 2} \sup_{1 \le k \le n} S_{n, k}
> $$
> is finite or not?

---

**My attempt** We have
$$
\begin{align*}
S_{n,k} &= 1+ \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} \frac{t_{n, i+1} - t_{n, i}}{\sum_{j=i}^{k-1} t_{n, j+1} - t_{n, j}} \\
&= 1 +  \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} \frac{1}{(n-i)^2 \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(n-j)^2}}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
S_{n, n} &= 1 +  \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(n-i)^2 \sum_{j=i}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-j)^2}} \\
&\le 1 +  \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(n-i)^2} \\
&\le 1+ \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{align*}
$$

Than I'm stuck at upper bounding $\sup_{1 \le k \le n-1} S_{n, k}$.

Comment: The last step of $S_{n,n}$ does not seem correct to me.

Comment: @Youem could you elaborate more?

Comment: I don't see why $S_{n,k}$ is increasing in $k$ for fixed $n$, as the denominator in the sum also increases if $k$ increases.

Comment: @stange I did not claim that $(S_{n,k})_{k=1}^{n}$ is increasing.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I thought you just wanted someone to check your proof, hence my wondering.

Comment: @Akira I added an answer with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_{n, k} = 1 + \sum_{\ell = n-k-2}^{n} \frac1{\ell^2} \times \frac1{\sum_{j=n-k-2}^\ell\frac1{j^2}}$$

Let $m=n-k-2$, then

\begin{align}
S_{n,k} &= 1 + \sum_{\ell = m}^{n} \frac1{\ell^2}\times\frac1{\sum_{j=m}^\ell \frac1{j^2}}\\
&\ge \sum_{\ell = m}^n \frac1{\ell^2} \frac1{\displaystyle\int_{m-1}^{\ell}\frac1{x^2}\mathrm d x}\\
&= \sum_{\ell = m}^n \frac{m-1}{\ell(\ell - m + 1)}\\
&= \sum_{\ell=m}^n \frac{1}{\ell - m + 1} - \sum_{\ell=m}^{n}\frac1\ell\\
&= H_{n-m+1} - \left(H_n - H_{m-1}\right) 
\end{align}

This proves that $$S_{2n, n-1} \ge H_{n} - H_{2n} + H_{n-2} \to \infty$$

since $\ln n - \ln (2n) + \ln (n-2) = \ln(n-2) - \ln (2)\to \infty$

This proves that $\alpha = \infty$.